# sequence generation in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I have one field in my table and values for that field willbe generated by the sequence which i have given in hbm mapping. now my question is, if i provide value for these field which has mapped with sequence , what will happen? 
1. will hibernate ignore the value provided by me and it invoke its sequence?
or 
2. will it take the value given by me( i am expectiong invoking sequence will not happen)?

Answer (score 1):

It will be an error- either you tell NH that the number is autogenerated, or you give NH the number. it can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases there should not be need to modify such column directly - for example 'version' managed by Hibernate.